# Advanced forum - search view

Tags: 7, search, nodes

The advanced forum module has search implemented using a block. It works decently, however, when searching, it doesn't highlight the matched terms with some context, it just lists the matching threads.

Is there any way to modify it so that the actual matched text is displayed?

Comment: Have update my answer, in case if you referred my previous answer, thanks.

Comment: I understand your issue, I think you should created a new issue on the [module issue page](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/advanced_forum?categories=All). This is the module problem need to be addresed.